# StoredProcedures ... "The Request Properties cannot be supported"

Tags: sql-server-2005, asp-classic

I have a problem with SQL Server 2005 and classic asp and recordsets.

Whenever I modify a Table, it seems to affect all the stored procedures dependent on that table and when I call the (select) sproc, the error is:

"The Request Properties cannot be supported"

But when I run the sproc in query analyzer window, there are no problems.
And when I call the sproc via ado.net, no problems there too.

But when I open Management Studio as an admin, and alter the sprocs 1 by 1, and hit execute to alter them, everything starts working again.

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Can't say for sure why it's happening, but rather than altering the sprocs 1 by 1, you could try an [sp_recompile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181647.aspx) with the name of the table you've modified. This will flag all stored procedures and triggers that reference your table to recompile the next time they're run.

```
exec sp_recompile N'YourSchema.YourTable';
```

Comment: Thanks Joe,

That didn't help either.

Comment: For anybody else that **is** still having this problem, upgrading your sql-server to the latest service-pack and cumulative upgrade might help.